# Markevry in df.pyplot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem with function `markevry` in dataframe plot in pandas.
I want to mark the max value in every column on the plot. I tried compile this in Pycharm on python 3. My code as follow:

```
#projektII
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dane = pd.read_table('xxx.txt', names=('rok', 'kroliki', 'lisy', 'marchewki'))
df = pd.DataFrame(dane)

data = df[1:]
data=data.astype(float)
print(data)

markers_on  = data['kroliki'].max
markers_on2 = data['lisy'].max
markers_on3 = data['marchewki'].max

ax = plt.gca()

data.plot(kind='line',x='rok',y='kroliki', color = 'blue',ax=ax, markevry = [markers_on])
data.plot(kind='line',x='rok',y='lisy', color='red', ax=ax, markevry = [markers_on2])
data.plot(kind='line',x='rok',y='marchewki',color = 'orange',ax=ax, markevry = [markers_on3])

ax.set_xlabel("rok")
ax.set_ylabel("ilosc")
plt.show()
```

But I see this kind of error every time:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/X", line 18, in <module>
    data.plot(kind='line',x='rok',y='kroliki', color = 'blue',ax=ax, markevry = [markers_on])

  File "C:\Users\X\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 2941, in __call__
    sort_columns=sort_columns, **kwds)

  File "C:\Users\X\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 1977, in plot_frame
    **kwds)

  File "C:\Users\X\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 1804, in _plot
    plot_obj.generate()

  File "C:\Users\X\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 260, in generate
    self._make_plot()

  File "C:\Users\X\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 985, in _make_plot
    **kwds)
 ...

  File "C:\Users\MX\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 912, in _update_property
    raise AttributeError('Unknown property %s' % k)

AttributeError: Unknown property markevry
```

If someone know what is wrong with this code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1st Change:
try adjust these:

```
markers_on  = data['kroliki'].max
markers_on2 = data['lisy'].max
markers_on3 = data['marchewki'].max
```

to this:

```
markers_on  = data['kroliki'].max()
markers_on2 = data['lisy'].max()
markers_on3 = data['marchewki'].max()
```

2nd Change: try adjust these:

```
data.plot(kind='line',x='rok',y='kroliki', color = 'blue',ax=ax, markevry = [markers_on])
data.plot(kind='line',x='rok',y='lisy', color='red', ax=ax, markevry = [markers_on2])
data.plot(kind='line',x='rok',y='marchewki',color = 'orange',ax=ax, markevry = [markers_on3])
```

to

```
data.plot(kind='line',x='rok',y='kroliki', color = 'blue',ax=ax, markevry = markers_on)
data.plot(kind='line',x='rok',y='lisy', color='red', ax=ax, markevry = markers_on2)
data.plot(kind='line',x='rok',y='marchewki',color = 'orange',ax=ax, markevry = markers_on3)
```

I think this should work!

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still the same

Comment: adjusted my codes. two issues in total i think @Wiill.I.Am